# UnitOfWork with NInject design issues

Tags: ninject, unit-of-work

I have my UnitOfWork class in DataAccess project and to resolve my IUnitOfWork interface (with UnitOfWork class), I need to use Ninject to Bind the IUnitOfWork interface with UnitOfWork class in my web project.

To do this I need to refer my DataAccess project (which contains UnitOfWork class) in the Web project. Is this good design wise? I mean referring DataAccess in the web project seems to be a bad idea & I never did that.

So, please advise me on what to do?

Comment: Can you add some detail as to what bit isnt covered  well by https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel ? Perhaps it may help identify shortcomings in the article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not comfortable having reference to DataAccess project (*imho it is not a big issue*) you can create separate project (let's call it ModuleProject) that will contain `NinjectModule`s. ModuleProject will have references to both DataAccess and to project where `IUnitOfWork` is defined. In your web project you will have reference to ModuleProject and use its classes to register modules.

**Module**

```
public class NinjectConfiguration : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

**Registration in web project**

```
kernel.Load(new Mod.NinjectConfiguration());
```

More information on modules [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel).