# How to handle different Ninject scopes for shared library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

I have a shared library that uses the Entity Framework (DbContext).  This library is used in normal windows applications as well in a web MVC project.  I'm using Ninject as DI.

It's my understanding I should be using `InThreadScope` on the `DbContext` for Windows applications and `InRequestScope` for the MVC project.

This however creates some unwanted dependencies. Either my shared library needs a reference to `System.Web` (for request scoping).  Or my web project needs a reference to EF (so I can change scope).

Is it possible to setup Ninject in such a way to avoid these dependencies?

Comment: So i gather your applications do not directly need DbContext. What are they referencing which uses DbContext?

Comment: Sorry, this is what i wanted to edit my comment to (but got disrupted): In case there is a 1:1:1 relation between (Thread/Request):Dependency:DbContext, you could also define scope constraints between Dependency:DbContext @ shared library and Thread:Dependency @ WinApp and Request:Dependency WebApp. This would neither require any additional projects nor references.
But this is only possible if there is some kind of 1:...:1...:1 dependency involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new project like *NinjectModules*. Move declaration of bindings into separate modules like *WinAppModule*, *MvcModule* and put it into *NinjectModules* project. Then reference *NinjectModules* from win app project and mvc project. They won't need to reference EF and `System.Web` anymore.

**UPDATE**

[image: Modules diagram]
*You can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511294/1193333) on similar question.*

Comment: Two separate assemblies for 1 line of code each?  Don't think my body would let me type that code.

Comment: No, just one additional assembly for ninject modules binding declaration.

Comment: I have added diagram to help you understand. *Keep im mind, you shoud never declare IOC bindings inside a library project (the user of library should decide, which bindings to use. This way you will also stay independent on the IOC container implementation (the depencdency will be declared only in the top most projects).*

Comment: Don't agree.  It's perfectly fine to use IOC inside a library project.  Often there is no need to expose internal functionality to calling project.  All I'm looking for is a way to pass a scope object to the library. Pretty sure now that this is not possible with Ninject at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i made a drawing:
[image: moving the binding dependency to the intermediary]
Often times one uses some representation of the "database session" like UnitOfWork.
So if your shared library "SomeLib" offers IUnitOfWork to represent the session, you might create a 1:1 binding IUnitOfWork:DbContext @ SomeLib and a more specific binding in your application.

Comment: How do you bind just the interface?  Or are you suggesting wrapping DbContext in UnitOfWork wrapper?  Wouldn't this have the same issue?

Comment: Yes basically i'm suggesting wrapping DbContext in UnitOfWork. As long as the interface of UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork does not contain anything related to the EF library you won't need a reference to it. However since i'm not familiar with EF i don't know whether it's a good fit to do so or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possible solution would be:

In SomeLib define the binding for DbContext as follows:

```
this.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf()
    .InScope(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<IDbContextScopeRetriever>().Retrieve());`
```

[image: using a scope retriever]
Then create and bind the respective implementations of `IDbContextScopeRetriever` in your applications.

The implementation of `ThreadDbContextScopeRetriever` might be:

```
object Retrieve() {
    return System.Threading.Current;
}
```

Comment: I've tried something similar, passing the scope lamba straight to the NinjectModule.  This works fine except that the scope lamba for InRequestScope is private.  Ofc I can rip out the implementation but that kind of hack defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I don't know how complex InRequestScope is (github web is currently unreachable from here) so i reckon it might be worse than having an unwanted reference. (InThreadScope is really easy, as shown in the answer).